# Python version in a conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, virtual-environment

I would like to know which python version is installed in the virtual environment I am in.

Using `python -V` in the terminal within a python environment is showing me the wrong version (of the base environment). The result is the same when executing `!python -V` in the jupyter notebook within this environment. When opening the python shell by typing `python` in the terminal, the shell with correct python version is being opened. Also, `which python` is showing the path of python in the environment.

Why is `python -V` not showing the python version of the current environment?

Also, the following python code is showing correct python version of the current environment:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
```

Comment: Presumably because the `python` on your PATH is not what you think it is. What does `which python` tell you? (My guess is it's not what `sys.executable` is.)

Comment: `which python` and `sys.executable` is giving the same output which also is the expected output. I have mentioned this already in the description of my question.

Comment: What terminal? The Jupyter one?

Comment: Same result in terminals of both Jupyter Lab and desktop. @merv

Comment: Is there an alias perhaps? (check `type python`)

Comment: `which python` and `type python` showing similar output. @merv